# IIS Freezes up with making call (only from IE11)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, iis, internet-explorer-11

I'm running a ASP.NET MVC (4.5) app.  I can access everything fine on Chrome, FireFox, Safari, and Edge.  When I try and access the site in IE11, I can login, access the main landing page, and click on any one of a number of links.  When I click a link, it is supposed to open up in an iframe.  From what I can tell, all of the Javascript behind the scenes works fine.  What happens is that the link never gets called.  I can even open the link in another window (which works in other browsers) and nothing ever happens.  I brought up the development console, and nothing shows up for the next page.  I even tried using Fiddler.  It can't find anything either.  Sometimes it timesout.  Sometimes NO CALL is made.

I'm running everything on Windows 10x64 with the latest updates.
We recently updated JQUERY to 3.x (latest).  Before the change, IE did work.  Thing is, the page being redirected to should still load when typed into a new tab.  I'm not convinced this is a jquery issue.

Once the attempt is made in IE11 (even in simulated other versions), the IIS server seizes up and doesn't respond to any calls at all.  This is true even for things in a different app pool.

No jquery/browser combo should be able to seize up IIS, right?

If anyone has any ideas as to what is causing this issue, I'm all ears.

Thanks in advance.

Update: this site may have a fix: https://forums.asp.net/t/1888889.aspx?Question+regarding+a+possible+bug+within+NET+4+5

Our staging servers don't have this issue.  Its just the local Windows 10 boxes.  We're thinking its an IIS server issue.  We'll have more info with 48 hours.

Update 2: We're running IIS 10 Express.  IIS is definitely affected.  One of the app pools does seem to be working.  The other two fail.  The network tab doesn't show any calls of any kind of relevancy.  The IIS logs don't show anything helpful either.

Update 3: it seems to be server related.  This issue only occurs on our local machines.

Comment: javascript can definitely seize up a browser. But it wouldn't affect IIS. What does the network tab look like - (you may need to turn of clear for new navigation). Surely the browser submits a http request (it would have to to affect IIS in any way). Its interesting that it affects IIS across all app pools. Those things are meant to be isolated. What version of IIS, and do IIS or windows logs give any clues?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid See update 2.  And thanks for the help.

Comment: The computer is probably entering an infinite loop... Does the CPU, memory usage goes up when this happens?